# Inconsistent characters per lines in Laravel Snappy

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, snappy, laravel-snappy

I have been working with Laravel Snappy (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy) for PDF generation.
After applying a combination of settings (word break applied), Snappy PDF takes `108 characters per line` with Mono-space font "Roboto Mono". However, when I add two different text strings with same number of characters, Snappy prints one string with 108 characters in same line and other string with 108 characters in two lines.

**Strings used**

*String 1:*

governments but it was ineffectual at providing stability as it could not collect taxes and had no executive
(108 characters)

*String 2:*

century away from more densely populated lifestyles and towards reorganized polities elsewhere. The European
(108 characters)

Following style and html are as follows:

`text_message.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <style type="text/css">
            * {
                overflow: visible !important;
                font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
            }
            @page {
                size: letter;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0 !important;
            }

            html body {
                min-width: initial !important;
                font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
                margin: 0 !important;
                padding: 0 !important;
            }
            .text-message {
                font-size: 14px;
                font-style: normal;
                line-height: 21px;
                letter-spacing: 0.045em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="letter">
        <section class="sheet break-after" style="position: relative;">
            <div class="text-message" style="word-break: break-word;">
                {!! nl2br($order->textMessage->message) !!}
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

For Laravel Snappy has following settings:

`GeneratePdf.php` Service class

```
$order = Order::find(200);
$pdf = SnappyPdf::setOption('enable-javascript', true);
$pdf->setOption('footer-font-size','8');
$pdf->setOption('footer-right', 'page [page] of [topage]');
$pdf->setOption('margin-top', 8);
$pdf->setOption('margin-bottom', 8);
$pdf->setOption('margin-left', '5');
$pdf->setOption('margin-right', '5');
$pdf->setOption('page-offset', '-2');

Storage::put('path/to/file', $pdf->getOutputFromHtml(view('text_message', compact('order'))));
```

Output by Snappy:

[Laravel Snappy PDF output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHqbs.png)

PDF link:
[order_pdf.pdf](https://docdro.id/N5TMiCB)

I need exactly same number of characters in every line as pricing depends on it. Can someone tell me why is it printing same number of characters in two different ways?

I added long string text to check how many characters Snappy takes in with the above style and font. I used that number of characters with two different strings. As it has mono space font, it should print both strings in single line and it should not break string 1 into two lines.